# return coefficients from Pipeline object in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, scikit-learn-pipeline

I've fit a `Pipeline` object with `RandomizedSearchCV`

```
pipe_sgd = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()),
                    ('clf', SGDClassifier(n_jobs=-1))])

param_dist_sgd = {'clf__loss': ['log'],
                 'clf__penalty': [None, 'l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet'],
                 'clf__alpha': np.linspace(0.15, 0.35),
                 'clf__n_iter': [3, 5, 7]}

sgd_randomized_pipe = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipe_sgd, 
                                         param_distributions=param_dist_sgd, 
                                         cv=3, n_iter=30, n_jobs=-1)

sgd_randomized_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I want to access the `coef_` attribute of the `best_estimator_` but I'm unable to do that. I've tried accessing `coef_` with the code below.

`sgd_randomized_pipe.best_estimator_.coef_`

However I get the following AttributeError...

AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'coef_'

The scikit-learn docs say that `coef_` is an attribute of `SGDClassifier`, which is the class of my `base_estimator_`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can always use the names you assigned to them while making the pipeline by using the `named_steps` dict.

```
scaler = sgd_randomized_pipe.best_estimator_.named_steps['scl']
classifier = sgd_randomized_pipe.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf']
```

and then access all the attributes like `coef_`, `intercept_` etc. which are available to corresponding fitted estimator.

This is the formal attribute exposed by the Pipeline as [specified in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

> **named_steps** : dict
>
> Read-only attribute to access any step parameter by user given name. Keys are step names and values are steps parameters.

Answer (score 14):

I think this should work:

```
sgd_randomized_pipe.named_steps['clf'].coef_
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found one way to do this is by chained indexing with the `steps` attribute...

`sgd_randomized_pipe.best_estimator_.steps[1][1].coef_`

Is this best practice, or is there another way?

Comment: The `named_steps` method describe above is preferred

Comment: This worked well when using `make_pipeline` with many different classifiers!

Answer (score 1):

In short, in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) there are two ways to access the estimators chained together in a [`Pipline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html): either retrieved by ***index*** or retrieved by ***name***. (And each way again has two flavours, i.e. *directly* vs. *indirectly*.)

---

Firstly, as the [User Guide of sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#construction) points out,

> The [`Pipline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) is built using ***a list of*** `(key, value)` pairs (**i.e. steps**), where the `key` is a string containing the ***name*** you want to give this step and `value` is an estimator object.

Which indicates that:

1. a `pipline` is constructed by one or multiple [estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-estimator) objects, in order. (just like a list)

   ```py
   >>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
   >>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
   >>> from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
   >>> estimators = [('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('clf', SVC())]
   >>> pipe = Pipeline(estimators)
   >>> pipe
   Pipeline(steps=[('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('clf', SVC())])
   ```
2. and each [estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-estimator) object has a *name*, either appointed by the user (with the `key`) or automatically set (e.g. by using [`make_pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html) utility function)

   ```py
   >>> from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
   >>> pipe = make_pipeline(PCA(), SVC())
   >>> pipe
   Pipeline(steps=[('pca', PCA()), ('svc', SVC())])
   ```

---

So finaly, we can access the estimators in a `Pipline` either

1. by ***indexing*** the Pipline:

   - directly through the `Pipline` object (just like a `list`)

     ```py
     >>> pipe[0]
     PCA()
     >>> pipe[1]
     SVC()
     ```
   - indirectly through [the `steps` attribute](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) (*actually* a list of tuple)

     ```py
     >>> pipe.steps
     [('pca', PCA()), ('svc', SVC())]
     >>> pipe.steps[0][1]
     PCA()
     >>> pipe.steps[1][1]
     SVC()
     ```
2. or by the ***name*** of steps/estimators:

   - directly through `Pipline` object (just like a `dict` or `namedtyple`)

     ```py
     >>> pipe["pca"]
     PCA()
     >>> pipe["svc"]
     SVC()
     ```
   - indirectly through [the `named_steps` attribute](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.named_steps) (*actually* a subclass of `dict`)

     ```py
     >>> pipe.named_steps
     {'pca': PCA(), 'svc': SVC()}
     >>> pipe.named_steps["pca"]
     PCA()
     >>> pipe.named_steps["svc"]
     SVC()
     ```

From here on, I hope we could play around the piplines like a skilled plumber.